# Forgot password not working

Tags: apex, community, forgot-your-password

I am trying to make use of the forgot password functionality in my community(aloha template). I am not sure what is going wrong. This is my component:

```
<!-- add implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" to surface the component in community builder --><aura:component controller="LightningForgotPasswordController">
<aura:attribute name="usernameLabel"        type="String" required="false" default="Your email address"/>
<aura:attribute name="passwordLabel"        type="String" required="false" default="Your Password"/>
<aura:attribute name="loginButtonLabel"     type="String" required="false" default="LOG IN"/>
<aura:attribute name="RegisterButtonLabel"  type="String" required="false" default="SIGN UP"/>
<aura:attribute name="cancelButtonLabel"    type="String" required="false" default="Cancel"/>
<aura:attribute name="sendEmailButtonLabel" type="String" required="false" default="SEND EMAIL"/>
<aura:attribute name="labels"               type="Object"   description="labels of the fields"/>
<aura:attribute name="stepnumber"       access="public"             type="integer"  description="number of step"/>
<aura:attribute name="isManditory"      type="boolean"      default="true"  access="public" />
<aura:attribute name="showError" type="Boolean" required="true" description="" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="errorMessage" type="String" required="false" description="" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="checkEmailUrl" type="String" required="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="submitButtonLabel" type="String" required="false" default="Send Password Reset Email"/>

<div class="slds-grid">

    <div class="slds-col ">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
            <div class="start_middle"> 

                <div class=" slds-card slds-p-left--xx-large cardWidth ">



                    <div class="slds-text-heading--large slds-p-top--large slds-p-bottom--medium boldFont "><b>{!$Label.c.B2B_Partners_Forgot_Password}</b></div>
                    <p class="slds-theme--shade lightFont">{!$Label.c.B2B_Partners_Forgot_Password_Body} </p>


                    <div id="sfdc_username_container" class="slds-form slds-p-top--medium">
                        <lightning:input type="email" aura:id="username" value="" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input--bare slds-has-divider--bottom input sfdc_usernameinput sfdc"  name="username" label="{!v.labels.email__c+' '}" onchange="{!c.onKeyUp}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-text-align--right slds-p-top--xx-large">
                        <lightning:button label="{!v.cancelButtonLabel}" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.onClickStep1}" iconName="utility:left" class=" pressed bookFontLink"/>
                        <lightning:button label="{!v.sendEmailButtonLabel}" aura:id="submitButton" variant="brand"  onclick="{!c.handleForgotPassword}"  class="slds-p-left--medium  sfdc_button boldFontWhite"/>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my javascript controller:

```
handleForgotPassword: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.forgotPassword(component, event, helper);
    console.log('FGPW2')
    var stepnumber     = component.get('v.stepnumber');
    component.set('v.stepnumber', stepnumber=3);
},

onKeyUp: function(component, event, helper){
//checks for "enter" key
if (event.getParam('keyCode')===13) {
    helper.handleForgotPassword(component, event, helper);
}
}
```

This is my helper:

```
 ({
  forgotPassword: function (component, event, helper) {

    var username = component.find("username").get("v.value");
    var checkEmailUrl = './login2';
    var action = component.get("c.resetPassword");

    action.setParams({username:username, checkEmailUrl:checkEmailUrl});
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
      var rtnValue = a.getReturnValue();
      console.log('rtnValue'+rtnValue)
      if (rtnValue != null) {
       component.set("v.errorMessage",rtnValue);
       component.set("v.showError",true);
         console.log('rtnValue'+rtnValue)
      }
    });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }
 })
```

This is my apex class:

```
 global class LightningForgotPasswordController {

public LightningForgotPasswordController() {

}

@AuraEnabled
public static String resetPassword(String username, String checkEmailUrl) {
    try {
        Site.forgotPassword(username);
        ApexPages.PageReference checkEmailRef = new PageReference(checkEmailUrl);
        if(!Site.isValidUsername(username)) {
            return Label.Site.invalid_email;
        }
        aura.redirect(checkEmailRef);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

I am sending my username correctly back to the class. But it is not sending the email. How do I solve this? I have verified in Setup -> Email Administration -> Deliverability that Access Level is set to 'All email'. I am trying to reset in the community. And the email template is configured in the right way. Any ideas?

Comment: Apex is a weak spot of me, can anyone confirm that this class is correct or wrong? Thanks

Comment: Site.forgotPassword(username) method resets the password and sends an email. where are you calling that in your apex class?. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm